# How to identify packets of traceroute?

Tags: c, networking, wireshark, pcap, traceroute

I'm working in C and using the `pcap` library to analyze a cap file that has packets that were sent/received during the execution of `traceroute`. The problem I'm having is identifying packets that were sent/received from the `traceroute` since the cap file includes other packets as well.

Is there any specific criteria I could check against when trying to determine if any given packet is from `traceroute`? Or is this not possible?

Would appreciate any help/advice you could offer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ man traceroute

TRACEROUTE(8)             BSD System Manager's Manual            TRACEROUTE(8)

NAME
     traceroute -- print the route packets take to network host

    ...


     -I      Use ICMP ECHO instead of UDP datagrams.  (A synonym for "-P
             icmp"). 

    ...


     This program attempts to trace the route an IP packet would follow to   
     some internet host by launching UDP probe packets with a small ttl (time
     to live) then listening for an ICMP "time exceeded" reply from a gateway.
     We start our probes with a ttl of one and increase by one until we get an
     ICMP "port unreachable" (which means we got to "host") or hit a max 
     (which defaults to net.inet.ip.ttl hops & can be changed with the -m
     flag).  Three probes (changed with -q flag) are sent at each ttl setting
     and a line is printed showing the ttl, address of the gateway and round
     trip time of each probe.  If the probe answers come from different gate-
     ways, the address of each responding system will be printed.  If there is
     no response within a 5 sec. timeout interval (changed with the -w flag),
     a "*" is printed for that probe.

     We don't want the destination host to process the UDP probe packets so
     the destination port is set to an unlikely value (if some clod on the  
     destination is using that value, it can be changed with the -p flag).
```

So, by default, traceroute packets are UDP packets sent to some random port; that makes them somewhat hard to distinguish from other traffic.

*If* somebody uses the `-I` option, it'll use ICMP ECHO packets, which are easier to distinguish from other traffic, although not easier to distinguish from, for example, traffic from the "ping" command.

You *could* try looking for packets with a small TTL.

Comment: I think the definitive conclusion is that there is no real way to check whether these packets belong to the traceroute.

Answer (score 0):

The program traceroute work by sending UDP/ICMP packets with incrementing IP TTL field. These IP TTL field are typically very small compared to what a typical application will send (in mine is 64).

So if you capture with filter with

ip.ttl < 20

You may get these packets (you may tweak the number in the above filter), remember, if your are close to the host that run traceroute program, you can even catch it by  "ip.ttl < 5".